# Creating a query that queries the data in a table more than once

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of data of personal details of clients:

```
ID
name
addressID
referralID
```

Part of the data is a 'referralID'. This will be filled in for some entries if they have been referred by other clients in the database. Therefore the referralID will match up to an ID in the database.

I'm trying to create a query that will return the details of the referrers and the names of the people that they have referred e.g:

```
Referrals ID (Where referallID = ID), 
Referrals name (name), 
ID of client referred (ID), 
Name of Client referred (name)
```

I'm having difficulty in how to approach this and what method to undertake as the query needs to reference itself in some way? How can i extract the details twice from the table?

Hope that is easy enough for someone to understand. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, cheers

Comment: Look at using left join to itself assuming the referralID is in the client table.  IT would also help to see the exact table structure.

Comment: self join, that is you can join table with itself, e.g.
select * from table t1 Inner Join Table t2 ON t1.id = t2.referralid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `MyTable` with the name of your table and join to the same table using aliases:

```
SELECT 
     m.ID, 
     m.Name, 
     m.AddressID, 
     m2.name as ReferralName 
FROM 
     MyTable m
INNER JOIN 
     MyTable m2 
ON m2.ReferralID = m.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a list of all clients and the people they referred and that client is the table name and that ID=ReferallID...

```
Select * from client c1
LEFT join client c2 on C1.ID = C2.ReferallID
```

Comment: Always list your columns explicitly, never return `*` even if you want all the columns.  You also don't alias out the ReferralName so it becomes difficult in the query to understand who is the referral.

Comment: @JonH, am I right in saying you should never use * ? Is this only a performance issue?

Comment: You should never use `*` when writing SQL queries, it is never necessary.  You should explicitly write out ALL column names to avoid issues with performance and pulling out large amounts of data from the database.  You also avoid naming conflicts between joined queries in the case that you don't use aliases.

Comment: Cheers @JonH i will take that advice on board